# Laravel Spark - How to avoid the need to put the billing information twice

Tags: laravel-spark

In Laravel Spark you can set the option that when the customers creates their account the system show them the form to fill the billing address & VAT no.

Unfortunately to have the correct data on the invoice they have to go to /settings#/invoices to fill in the data after finish all the registration process, confirming their email and log-in.

This is very inconvenient as nobody understand this step and there where 0 (zero) customers of over 500 we have until now who actually find this field and filled it up. They just complain that the invoice is incorrect and we have to send corrections.

So my question is:
Is there a way to put the "Extra billing information" field which is here /settings#/invoices on the registration front so the customer will be able to fill it in during the registration process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to follow the same steps like with adding any other field to the registration form because the company data are stored in `extra_billing_information` column in `users` table.

Reference: https://www.core45.com/en/blog/how-to-add-customera-company-data-for-invoice-on-the-registration-form-in-laravel-spark